# Is there a way to tell which set a list item came from?

Tags: python

I currently have this working to where it outputs any changes made to the sitemap.

What I want is for it to show if the change was removed or added. I figured I could do this by somehow finding out which list the output came from.

i.e
If was the old list was missing something the new one had I would know it was ADDED
If the new list was missing something the old one had I would know that something was REMOVED

I haven't been able to find much about this specifically, I'm still looking into it.

Note: I have already tried difflib. I DO NOT like the output. I currently have a working program using difflib, but the output is a mess. Figured it be easier (Output wise) to just make my own.

My ultimate goal with this is to monitor a sitemap.xml and print any changes and also print whether it was added, removed or an edit.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv
  
# field names 
fields = ['Test', 'Test2', 'Test3'] 
    

# target URL
url = "https://www.huntermichaelseo.com/testing.xml"

# act like a browser
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

PrevVersion = ""
FirstRun = True


while True:
   # download the page
  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  # parse the downloaded homepage
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "xml")
  this = soup.find_all('loc')
  if PrevVersion != this:
    if FirstRun == True:
      PrevVersion = this
      FirstRun = False
      print ("Start Monitoring "+url+ " "+ str(datetime.now()))


      # remove all scripts and styles
      
    else:
      print("Changes detected on MDR at: "+ str(datetime.now()))

      OldPage = set(PrevVersion)
      NewPage = set(soup.find_all('loc'))
      another = str(OldPage ^ NewPage).split(", ")
      s = '\t'.join(str(x2) for x2 in another)   
      print(s)
      with open('GFG', 'w') as f:
      
        # using csv.writer method from CSV package
        write = csv.writer(f)
          
        write.writerow(fields)
        write.writerows(another)
        OldPage = NewPage
      #print ('\n'.join(diff))
      PrevVersion = this
      
  else:
    print( "\nNo Changes to MDR "+ str(datetime.now()))
  time.sleep(5)
  continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tell which set a value came from when you use `oldPage ^ newPage`. Use subtraction to get each difference.

```
added = newPage - oldPage
deleted = oldPage - newPage
```

Then when you're writing these to the CSV file, you can add a label to each row indicating which set it came from.